# List Density Plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

What are the axis label for a list density plot? I have it set up to create the plot for 2 columns from a data set I got from an experiment, I'm just unsure of what each axis is supposed to be.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may help you:

```
GraphicsRow[{ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], ColorFunction -> Hue], 
             Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> Hue]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Use the `DataRange` option: `ListDensityPlot[Table[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3, .1}, {y, 0, 3, .1}], ColorFunction -> Hue, DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}]`